# How to schedule PostgreSQL replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, scripting, scheduled-tasks

I was reading postgresql replications solution but, even I just starting understaning how it works, another doubt has arrisen.
I'll be using postgres internal replication solution but as far as I understand, every event will be replicated just as it is achieved; for example, if I insert some data into the master, automatically it will be replicated to the slave...Am I right?

Well, is that so, I was searching for way of scheduling this replications as a passive backup but the thing is, I need for example, every monday on the night the database gets replicated with all the data it had inserted in it that day to a slave database in Amazon EC2 virtual servers. I was thinking on using cron as a first approach but reading postgres documentation I got aware that practically only configuring the necessary files, postgres do it for you...

So, how could I schedule replication in just desired moments?

PD.-The schedule may vary so it needs to be completely generic, also...I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and PostgreSQL 9.1 as in the master as in the slave.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pg_basebackup` to take a copy of the PostgreSQL database over the replication protocol. It copies the whole DB though, it isn't incremental. You'll want to use the `--xlog-method=stream` argument unless you have a shared WAL archive set up.

Streaming replication isn't really well suited to the purpose you describe. You can set it to have replication lag, but it's more minutes or hours rather than days, as the amount of WAL you have to retain on the master or in an archive to get days of replication lag is huge. It's also fixed, not schedulable.

You could achieve what you describe with lots of WAL archiving plus a custom-created recovery.conf for each backup, but it'll be fiddly at best.

The thing you need to realise is that by (say) Friday, the master no longer has any record of the state it was in on Monday. It can't update last Friday's snapshot to this Friday because it no longer knows what state it was in on intermediate days like last Monday ... or last Friday. It doesn't know what state the old replica is in, nor how to get it from there to where it is now.

You can tell it to remember that much state by archiving WAL segments, but you need an immense amount of disk space for that and it's very inefficient to catch the backup up from WAL if your DB is busy.

I'd recommend just using `pg_basebackup` and/or `pg_dump` on a schedule.

Comment: I think I'll use that. I was thinking using `pg_dump` since the beginning but my question as ¿ How will I update the slave database in order to be up-to-date with the master?
Can I have a little script adding the dump to the slave database every time a dump schedule is sent?
Or would it overwrite all the database data in the slave replica?

Comment: @Kronos It will overwrite the DB in the downstream (backup) DB. You save the dump to files and store the files. If you want an online history you can use point in time recovery (WAL archiving) on a hot standby plus a `recovery.conf` that you advance periodically then restart the replica. It's a bit clumsy but it works. Alternately, create new databases like "backup_2012_01_01", "backup_2012_01_02", etc. Have your script restore to the named database and drop the oldest one.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question, but I had the same question today. One approach to do this is to schedule those commands for pausing and resuming replication.

```sql
-- to pause replication:
SELECT pg_wal_replay_pause();

-- to verify the state of the replication:
SELECT pg_get_wal_replay_pause_state();

-- to resume the replication
SELECT pg_wal_replay_resume();
```

You can check more about the history of this command here: https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_wal_replay_pause.html (e.g. from what versions onwards and there has also been a rename to this function).